# Interface with static IP that answers pings, but doesn't route outgoing connections

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have an old Linux computer_1 with 2 network interfaces: `wlan0` and `eth0`. There's no `iptables` there, but there is the `ip` command. I cannot install extra software there.

I assign `eth0` a static IP address `192.168.3.33`.

There is computer_2 connected to `eth0` with a crossover cable. computer_2 needs to ping computer_1's `eth0` as `192.168.3.33`.

Everything else, including connections to `192.168.3.*`, should be routed through `wlan0`.

So, I do:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.33 netmask 255.255.255.0
$ route
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.3.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.131.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.131.130 localhost       255.255.255.255 UGH   303    0        0 lo
```

This way, connections to `192.168.3.*` are routed through `eth0`. Not what I need.

If I try to

```
route del -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

afterwards, computer_2 won't receive responses to its pings.

Can `eth0` be made to respond to pings, and route everything else through wlan0?

Allowing icmp only on `eth0` will be fine.

Comment: The effect of deleting the route is to be expected. Is it worth the trouble to send everything else through WLAN if you have a perfectly good cable between the machines?

Comment: Yes it is worth it. There should be a connection to the whole network through `wlan0`, and no, computer_2 cannot be made a router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 192.168.3.0/24 is your local WLAN network, assign an address from some other network to eth0.

Comment: Thought of it, but then this some other network would be blocked. Maybe not a big deal, but I'd like to know if a perfect solution would be possible.

Comment: `192.0.2.0/24` should be fine, I believe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

Comment: Yes, any private address can't be used on the internet, and you know what networks you use on your own network, so you can pick something you don't use elsewhere.